# SyntaxError Invalid character '\u8220'

Tags: javascript, sqlite, gtk, gedit, geany

There is a GTK+ Javascript ( Seed ) Database Tutorial here: 
[Javascript GTK+ Seed SqLite Tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Seed/Tutorial/sqlite#Create_dbase)

When I cut and paste the code into Geany or Gedit and compile it throws this error:

```
** (seed:19814): CRITICAL **: Line 3 in ./db.js: SyntaxError Invalid character '\u8220'
```

After unsuccessfully trying to locate and delete the offending character not once but countless times I gave up. Then I simply typed all the code into Geany and then it compiles and executes no errors .

My question is do we have a way for Geany or Gedit to actually display or even place mark such invisible characters as typing in small programs I have no issues with but as they become larger then it becomes exceedingly weary and inefficient, especially when one is trying to learn a new framework.

My apologies if this is not a proper question for Stackoverflow but I truly am trying to understand how the cutting and pasting process adds in these characters, I have looked through the html and I see no such character in the tutorial.

The whole point of having sample code is to allow the end-user to cut and paste and compile and learn ? But this gave me a real bad headache till I finally decided to type it all in and then everything works.

Comment: You can always use `od` to dump out a file and look for funny characters.

Comment: Thank you Pointy that is a nifty tool I had no idea of but how does one edit and correct the offending character(s) as once loaded into Geany or Gedit both do not display them.

Comment: Well it depends on the editor. In this case, that character looks like this: “  It looks like ordinary double-quotes if you're not paying close attention. In `gvim` you can search like this: `/[^ -~]/`

Comment: Your right and (ahem..) another valid reason to familiarize myself with gvim I guess :-) Thank you for the guidance much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your editors *are* displaying the offending character, you're just not recognizing it. The code point in the error message refers to the [left double quotation mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) character, which is indeed present in some examples on the [linked page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Seed/Tutorial/sqlite#Create_dbase). This is almost certainly an unintentional effect of some well-meaning text editing software. As you correctly point out, code examples *are* intended to be copied and pasted, and you should report a bug to the site admins.

To add to the confusion, the error message printed by Seed's JavaScript parser is wrong: it misrepresents the `\u201c` character (which has *decimal* code 8220) as `\u8220`. This is why attempts to search for `\u8220` fail.

To fix the problem in your file, you need to replace the character with an upright quotation mark. To search for an arbitrary Unicode character in a GTK-based text editor, press <kbd>ctrl-f</kbd> to initiate search and input the character by with <kbd>ctrl-shift-u</kbd> followed by the code point, in this case `201c`. You will need to do the same for the right quotation mark, whose hex code is `201d`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the clarity but I have a question, when I try to use <kbd>ctrl-shft-u<kbd> it shows me a character that looks Chinese or Japanese ? 舠 that is what is displayed when I type in u8220 what causes this and how do I resolve ? I accept your answer as correct but would be nice to know how to rectify this issue as well please.

Comment: @ArunaHewapathirane You're quite right, `\u8220` is a [completely different character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8220/index.htm)! It appears that the error message is *wrong* - the character is `\u201c`, not `\u8220` (8220 is its numeric code, though), so you need to use `ctrl-shift-u 201c` to find it. I've now updated the answer to explain the confusion.

Comment: @ArunaHewapathirane np; you might also want to report the bug to the maintainers of Seed or WebKit JavaScriptCore, depending on where the message is coming from. It's safe to assume that this error message bug has confused a lot of people by now.

Comment: the tutorial is on wiki.gnome.org I will create a user account and try to edit the page. Reporting to the maintainers I need to identify whether it is seed or webkit once I manage to do this will defintely file a bug thank's

Comment: I cleaned up the gnome wiki tutorial should be ok now and how did you identify the character as \u201c and not \u8220 ? Thank's !

Comment: @ArunaHewapathirane I googled `8220 unicode` and the first hit was [the smartquote](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm), which I easily found in the examples. Only later did I figure out that the page is not about `\u8220`, but about `\u201c`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33002/discussion-between-aruna-hewapathirane-and-user4815162342)